# How to Code in PHP for SEO and non SEO Url > Giving Choice to User

Tags: php

I am writting Code in PHP, and i want to give my user options to use SEO url or not to use SEO URL in admin panel.

he will be given .htaccess code to save in his current .htaccess page.

Now, by default there is no SEO URL.

Therefore I am coding in my php code like below >

```
<a href="<?php echo $domain."/".$cat_page.".php?id=".$cat_id."&title=".$title."&query=".$query; ?>/" ><?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

Now, When i have to allow the SEO Url,

How can i implement below link automatically, without editing any code and even in view source the SEO link is shown like below >

```
<a href="<?php echo $domain."/".$cat_page.".php/".$cat_id."/".$title."/".$query; ?>/" ><?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

Do i need to save the SEO code in database column. If yes how can i guess the SEO URL before the title and category is added.

IF on fly how can i implement the code in all pages whenever pages are requested.

Don't tell me , you have to do with **.htaccess** I know that, but whenever i load my page, in view source non-seo urls are shown and .htaccess has no effect too.. I want to show seo url in view source too.. How should i write in my php code, Give me Idea, so that i can start writting code for that and show you.

Thanks.

This is Deep request to all **moderators** and **staff** to not close this thread saying duplicate or useless or FAQ, I am Damn Serious and i want to learn it tonight, It has been too much pain in my ass and i can't find right solution till now.

I request all knowledgable LEETS , ELITES of PHP to help me in this.

Thanks once again

Comment: Every URL is a SEO URL as long as your URL follows [rfc2616 3.2.2 HTTP URL](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2) - period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i implement below link automatically, without editing any code
>   and even in view source the SEO link is shown like below >

You can't. You must rewrite all your old to code to new one.

Much better solution is to write function-helper or use framework, or use [Symfony2 Routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) apart of Symfony 2 framework.

Comment: Ok. So final Conclusion is, I need to re-write complete code.
Thank you. I will do them now.

Comment: You are welcome! I strongly recommend you to look on microframeworks like [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) or [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (last one is based on symfony 2 components)

Answer (score 1):

Step back a bit. The general saying is:

- [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

The next most important thing to keep in mind is, that what is talked about SEO often is a myth. Don't focus search engines, focus your users firsthand.

Users bookmark complex URIs. So do search engines. It actually is the reason we have search engines because we don't want to remember (or could remember) all URIs. Therefore it's important for your website that:

- [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

So not changing the URL layout can have greater benefits to SEO than most "SEO tutorials" would tell you. Focus your users instead, not the search engines. Search engines, if made well - like google - follow suit anyway.

Comment: Can't help but mention how old that resource is whenever I see it linked to. Look cool URIs, the truth in the content hasn't changed, so it's still as true as ever.

Comment: Yes, update the `<title>` tag when you've got deficits, it's much more important than the URL. It has been for *years*. I can't stress that enough for good webmastering. Don't believe the SEO hype, it's not all marketing in live, and black magic does not exist. Instead, breath hypertext.